# How can I make a power rail inactive when it's next to an active one?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm building a Minecart track. In order for it to work correctly, I need the minecart to stop in the middle of the track, and the best way to do that is to use a power rail that is not receiving a redstone signal.

The problem is that the inactive power rail needs to be placed close to a powered rail, and powered rails are made active if they are within 8(?) blocks of a redstone signal.

[image]

I want the powered rail on the stone block to be turned off.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to simply place a powered rail between two normal rails and not connect it to a power source. Normal rails do not "conduct" redstone power, so the setup in this screenshot results in the powered rail on the stone block being inactive.

[image]

Another option for tracks at least 10 blocks long is to place 1 powered rail connected to an active redstone source and 9 powered rails *not* directly connected to a redstone source. The last powered rail will then be inactive.

[image]

Comment: In the second solution you might have to consider [MC-957](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-957).